# Power BI - Stack chart sort by

Tags: powerbi

I have the below chart

[image]

that is sorted by the count for each of the bins. I try to sort it by days open starting from 0 - 5 days, 5 - 10 days etc...

I have added another table that has IDs for each of the bins (0 - 5 days is 1, 5 - 10 days is 2) but I am unable to use it to sort it.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you considered accepting any of the answers to your question?

Answer (score 4):

I do it always by adding dimension table for sorting purpose. Dim table for bins would look like this:
[image]

Then go to Data pane and set it up as shown in the picture below.

1. Select `Bin name` column
2. Choose `Modeling` from menu
3. `Sort by column` and here choose column `Bin order`

[image]

Then connect the Dim table to fact table:
[image]

While making visual choose `Bin name` from Dim Table not Fact Table!
[image]

Then the final thing is set up sorting in visual:
[image]

Here you have Dim and Fact table to reproduce exercise.

Dim Table:

```
let
    Source = Table.FromRows(Json.Document(Binary.Decompress(Binary.FromText("i45WcsrMUzDQNVXSUTJUitWB8E11DQ2AAkZwAUMDXSOQiDFcxAioByRigtBkoGsIVmSK0GZkoA0UMFOKjQUA", BinaryEncoding.Base64), Compression.Deflate)), let _t = ((type text) meta [Serialized.Text = true]) in type table [#"Bin name" = _t, #"Bin order" = _t]),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Bin name", type text}, {"Bin order", Int64.Type}})
in
    #"Changed Type"
```

Fact Table:

```
let
    Source = Table.FromRows(Json.Document(Binary.Decompress(Binary.FromText("jdAxDoAgDAXQq5iu0qQtVmX1GoQDuHj/0SoJCWVh5KefR8kZrvtZCBUCMJRQz4pMFkgLmFC+ZGuJWKefUUL+h6zbekJrd3OV1EvHhBSnJHLU6ak0QaWRil5SBw2/pwPEMzvtHrLnlRc=", BinaryEncoding.Base64), Compression.Deflate)), let _t = ((type text) meta [Serialized.Text = true]) in type table [#"Bin name" = _t, Frequency = _t]),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Bin name", type text}, {"Frequency", Int64.Type}})
in
    #"Changed Type"
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do a Sort by Column under the Modeling tab where you sort your bin name column by the ID value column.

Answer (score 0):

You need to :
Connect the bins (0-5),(5-10) columns from the two tables in your relationships.

In your second table, add a column called order: 1,2,3 for the bins (0-5), 5-10 respectively and so on

This should work