# How to set slicer value to first available value form table in Power BI?

Tags: api, powerbi, powerbi-desktop, power-bi-report-server

I have a requirement that the selected value in slicer must be valid.

Let us suppose if I select a value in Store slicer and that store gets deleted from the company. The slicer will still show its name with no data in visuals interacting with the slicer.

**Default Value Selected**

[image: Default Selected Slicer]

**Updated Slicer Value Manually**

[image: Updated Slicer]

But I want only the relevant store selected in my Store slicer. I know its slicer's property to retain the value which is set in it while publishing the report, but is there any workaround for it.

Comment: I'm not sure this will help, but you can add a filter to the slicer itself, therefore adding a measure based "validation" to the available values. ie: filter the slicer to keep only the values with "SalesAmount" >0. I'm not sure about what will happen to the selection if the currently selected value disappears tomorrow.

Comment: Thank you for the bounty. Would you mind accepting the answer?

Answer (score 2):

The essence of your question has been asked and covered in this thread:

[Initial value of Power BI slicer based on another slicer choice](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51822625/1903793)

The answer is NO, but I can propose a workaround.

1. In the dimension table with stores, add a calculated column `Rank` which will determine the store with the highest sales. You may use RANKX function for that.
2. Add `StoreName` calculated column which returns the text value `"The biggest store"` (or `"Top 1"` - or whatever) and original store names for all the other stores. Use IF.
3. Put the column `StoreName` which contains `"The biggest store"` value to the slicer.
4. Add a visual (card, table) where you will display the **original** name of currently selected store.
5. Sort the column `StoreName` by Rank column designed for that purpose so that `The biggest store` will float up to the top position in the slicer. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51871965/1903793) is how to sort the column by another column.

Since there is always a store with the highest sales you may always have that value ticked in the slicer and it will always show data.

In this example `"The biggest store"` is "Store for girls". I keep it selected on the slicer. Then I remove all the records of that store from fact table. Apply. And the slicer is still selected as `"The biggest store"` but now the biggest store means "Store for ladybirds".

[image]

Here is a sample file for download (with both approaches in M and DAX):

[M Default Slicer Value.pbix](https://drive.google.com/u/0/uc?id=18hEP_E0uz48yvXJllW3GhM66N0F0ifq6&export=download)

You can make DimStore table completely in DAX by adding calculated table:

```
DimStore_DAX = 
SUMMARIZECOLUMNS (
    Sales[Store],
    "Sales", [Sale],
    "Rank", RANKX ( ALL ( Sales[Store] ), [Sale] ),
    "StoreName", IF ( RANKX ( ALL ( Sales[Store] ), [Sale] ) = 1, "The biggest store", VALUES ( Sales[Store] )
    )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is happening only because it's your default value, otherwise the slicer should lose the values automatically once its deleted from your base. If possible, change your default to reflect a store value, of which you are certain that it's always going to be there. I believe the default value will get retained even if there is no data. Another way to do this could be to default to ALL stores and then let the user select what is needed. This may not be what you are looking for, since I am not aware of your specific requirements, but hopefully it helps you arrive at a solution.